# Delay while rendering images on HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, http, hololens, mjpeg, hololens-emulator

I developed an Unity app on the HoloLens Gen.1. The app renders images which are received via HTTP according to the principle of Motion Jpeg.

The "problem" I have is that the "video" has a delay of 3 Sec. to the original source.

Can somebody explan to me how it comes. Then I use the emulator there is almost no delay.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to analyze HoloLens' network latency with some professional tools? According to your description, it is possible due to your app has a delay when transferring data. Besides, since the hardware performance limitations of HoloLens, it is unlikely to run as fast as in a computer.